# Enter most recent date of a previous Type

Tags: sql

What I have...

[image: ![enter image description here]

What my goal is...

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: (1) Explain the logic.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) Where does the last row come from?

Comment: Table has multiple ID's that we either repair or PM.  I want to have the most recent instance where we PM a specific ID in a new column.  The top 2 lines show that we repaired ID 0909X on 11/19 & 10/26 and the most recent instance where we PM that ID was on 9/29

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last PM using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when type = 'PM' then date end) over (partition by class, id order by date) as prev_pm
from t;
```

I'm not sure if adding an extra row to the data is really what you want to ask, but you could use `union all` for that.

Comment: Forgot to add an extra column to show that there are multiple ID's in my dataset.  Apologies

Comment: @JBrewer . . . That only requires adding `id` to the `partition by`.